# Reference requests for articles and texts on circular definitions and circular proofs

Tags: reference-request

I vaguely recall reading an article from a journal about circular definitions, and another article about circular proofs, but I forgot the authors and also what journal it was from. So, can anyone help me by giving me references for research on the concept of circular definitions and circular proofs? I don't mind if no one mentions the same articles I was reading, I would still be interested in any articles or texts on the research of circular definitions and proofs.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4559345/129912) is a circular reference. (Sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Comment: See Jon Kenneth Barwise and Lawrence Stuart Moss, [**Vicious Circles. On the Mathematics of Non-Wellfounded Phenomena**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1575860082), CSLI Lecture Notes #60, 1996, x + 390 pages. **REVIEWS:** **[1]** [*Journal of Logic, Language and Information*](https://philarchive.org/archive/AKMJBA-2); **[2]** [*Modern Logic*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/modern-logic/volume-8/issue-1-2/Review-of-Jon-Barwise-and-Lawrence-Moss-Vicious-Circles-On/rml/1081878069.full); **[3]** [*Bulletin of the AMS*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1998-35-01/S0273-0979-98-00735-6/)